# can array of links be fetched / resolved in an Entry request

Tags: contentful

I am requesting a specific Entry and one of the fields of that Entry is an array of links.  Is there a way to get those links to be resolved and returned in the resulting JSON response?

I am trying this via curl

```
curl -v https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/o2bhdl4js7ak/entries/<entryID>?access_token=<accessToken>&include=2
```

The "include=n" parameter does not work in this particular case.  should it?

Here's a snippet with the field I expect to be resolved / expanded

```
"lessons": [
  {
    "sys": {
      "type": "Link",
      "linkType": "Entry",
      "id": "26hzvgmWtqOcKeoeMQOAoO"
    }
  }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Have another read of the Links page on Contentful Developer Documents.

[Contentful Developer Documents - Links](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/)

to get a relationship link into the json you are requesting then you change the request link slightly as documented. instead of using the entryID where you have it after the entries/ in your link in the question, use it as demonstrated below.

```
https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/oc3u7dt7mty5/entries?access_token=6cabb22c95d52aa7752fe70ae9b3271a1fc2decf7ae7d99ccd7dceba718980e6&content_type=3HjHXUYR3yyosUqAGmi8wu&fields.restaurantField.sys.id=2UmoQ8Bo4g4S82WmGiQIQE
```

It's been moved into the sys.id at the end of the URL.